# "A book to read" or "A book to read it"

Tags: infinitive-clauses

What is a difference between those two sentences ?

1. > I need a book to read on holiday.
2. > I need a book to read it on holiday.

Comment: If possible, can you tell us where the sentences come from, and whether they are your creations?

Comment: I have it to write on my notes.

Comment: "I have it to write on my notes."  is it correct sentence ?

Comment: I'm afraid not. "I have to write it on my notes" is, but it depends what you want to say.

Comment: I mean "It has been written on my notes"

Comment: In which case, "I have written it on my notes" - pronouns come after verbs.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from style, there's not much difference apart from the second sounding clunky and forced. if you're hell bent on using "it" in a sentence like that it may be worth using:

> I need a book so *[that]* I can read it on holiday.

But as I said, there's no explicit difference in the meaning.

Comment: The second one almost looks like it's begging for a comma: _I need a book, so I can read it on holiday._

Comment: A difference in style, I think :)